# How to do cross site form communication?

Tags: html, forms, security, cross-domain, credit-card

Honestly, I am not sure how to describe my specific problem but I can give a concrete example.

You have a web page that asks users to connect various social media accounts. Once they do this, you provide the connected accounts to a backend which can connect to each social media account (using oauth or auth or whatever) to pull different data and provide a social media analytics report. Assume this is all secure and safe, this is not the main concern.

Now suppose the following:
A third party website uses your services to determine if users can be eligible for sponsorship based on your analytics reports. They have their own form that they request users to fill out and at some point the form re-routes the user to your web page for the social media analytics part. Upon completion, your site must send that user back to the third party's website with the social media analytics report. How would you do this, securely?

I thought of something like the following:

1. The third party routes their user to your website by making a GET request with the following parameters: applicationId=some_third_party_application_id&callbackUrl=their_callback_url.
2. Your webpage could pull the applicationId and the callbackUrl from the parameters and cache it in localstorage or whatever.
3. The user goes through your flow by connecting various social media accounts and your webpage sends these connections to a server which computes the social media analytics report.
4. The analytics report id is returned to the webpage by your backend and now the webpage can send back this id of the analytics report to the callback url that was initially specified in step 1.
5. The flow resumes on the third party's webpage and they can then call another api of yours to get the analytics report details from the id of the report you sent back via the callback url.
6. The third party then uses the details of the report to determine if the applicant is worthy of sponsorship.

I guess another example of this flow could be like credit reports for like a car loan or something. You would apply for a loan on one website that integrates with a credit provider. The credit provider sends back the report to the auto loan provider and this is done seamlessly and securely.

How is this done/implemented in the examples I have outlined <s>securely</s>? Are my thoughts on the right track?

Comment: What do you mean, specifically, by "done securely"?  All of these actions could be secured (the data in transit, anyways) by HTTPS.  Data at rest is another story.  The specific applications used at each step of the process could have their own vulnerabilities.  Same with each server.  Every user visiting the site(s) could have a keylogger installed without their knowledge.  There are so many possible vectors.

Comment: I think I may have led you down the wrong train of thought here with the last sentence, my apologies. I am more interested in how this problem is solved as mentioned by my examples and if the proposed strategy I have outline is valid.

I'll post my concerns about the "secure" side of things in separate replies below as it's too long.

Comment: 1) How does my app make sure that the redirect to our site isn't from a malicious source? I think this isn't too hard, as our site could be pre-configured to verify domains/ips and even the callback urls (only serve requests to certain domains and verify that callback urls match a precofigured url)

Comment: 2) Our site's backend wouldn't store any of the social media content or user information, just the analytics report details mapped to the analytics report id. The report data could have all PII (personally identifiable information) removed, and only contain metrics specific to an analytics algorithm (engagement, post count etc.).

Comment: 3) Are specifying things like the callback url, the applicaiton id, and the report id in query parameters safe?
4) Our third party is liable for any security holes they may have on their end, we simply provide analytic reports. Even the applicaitonId may not be necessary if they do things in localstorage and cache. In the event they don't the applicationId could be used to keep track of an application on their end and our callback just restores that application.

Comment: 5) I'm not too worried about using oauth on our own web page to connect and authorize user social media accounts, none of this would be stored long term and a user would have to redo this process for a new analytics report.